# Restricting a part of a site according to IP

Tags: redirection

This question is closely related with GDPR, and having done my research I've come across [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/gdpr) which seems to offer a checklist type functionality for overall GDPR compliance.

However as part of a solution which I'm working on, we need can't afford to permanently block traffic from EU countries. Therefore I want to know of the best approach which I could take to setup IP redirect to,

1. Block access to our primary domain from any EU country
2. Allow access only to URLs in /eu sub folder for visitors from EU countries
3. Setup relevant redirects to and from /eu for "a" and "b" above
4. Provide a way for internal users to be able to access any URL of the site
5. The /eu portion of the site should have its own configuration for web analytics, subscriptions, forms etc

I found a couple of modules in drupal.org which could help with blocking the IPs but I'm not quite sure about the redirects and the other requirements in 4 and 5 above. Also I do not want to compromise on performance and speed, so any ideas and suggestions on the best way to get this implemented is greatly appreciated.

The last thing I want to do is to setup /eu as a separate Drupal site, but let me know if that is a better option

Comment: Instead of making your sie GDPR-compliant, it sounds like you want to introduce something like "apartheid" for EU-visitors, do I get that right?

Comment: When not really, but I do not want to take any unnecessary risks. So my strategy is to actually separate it using regionalized URLs (which also makes sense with my products being sold) and thereafter once I've learnt how the best practices are for data processing in EU, I shall gradually roll out the changes consistently throughout the whole site.

Comment: So any advise on how I can get those redirects setup the right way is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This module [smart ip](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_ip) it saves the users location from the ip in `$_SESSION`.

The features section, says that it integrates with rules, so it might be possible to create a rule that redirects the user.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9838434/6335551) takes care of your redirects. Maybe you could use the [domain access module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) to get unique settings for the EU and non EU sections?